Can a 4-d creature twist your right hand into a left hand without breaking it?
One way we can make our right hand a left hand is by looking at it in the mirror. But that's not a real hand, only an image of one. If we settle for a glove, we can turn a right glove inside out and it becomes a left glove. We obviously wouldn't like it very much if this happened to our right hand.
Given that reflections are just rotations in higher dimensions, can a four dimensional creature grab our right hand and rotate it in a way that it becomes indistinguishable from our left hand?
Or say we have two right gloves with fleece lining on the inside. Can a 4-d creature "fix" this and turn one of the right gloves into a left glove in a way that its still usable?
Bonus: Can it do this without hurting us (can make some simplifying assumptions about the rotational capabilities of joints)?
Side note: From the answers, it seems like completely flipping a human into its mirror image is possible by a 4-d creature. Not only would the flipped human be left-handed (if they were right handed before), all the molecules in their body would also be flipped. This leads to interesting biological implications, see here (the qn was closed on Biology stackexchange, so I headed to Reddit): https://www.reddit.com/r/biology/comments/1hjv0e7/would_a_chirally_flipped_human_survive/.

Did you try writing down some matrices?

I'm guessing a 4-d rotation matrix? Let me think about it.

The constraints on the question are quite unclear to me, but perhaps sphere eversion is relevant. "Reflections are just rotations in higher dimensions"--well, no, they flip orientation. "Rotations" generally means $SO(n)$, while reflections are in $O(n) - SO(n)$.

If I have a triangle on my table with red, green and blue vertices, and going from red to blue to green is clockwise, then rotating it on the table will keep that motion clockwise. But if I lift it up and flip it over, going from red to blue to green will become counter-clockwise. Isn't this the same as flipping its orientation? And wasn't this achieved with a 3-d rotation?

If you consider the 3-d hand to produce a 4-d "world line" as it moves, then the 4-d creature couldn't turn it into the opposite hand without also reversing time for it.  Leaving as a comment, though, since that doesn't seem to be the situation you're asking about.

A lower-dimensional analogy might be illustrative here: take a piece of paper and cut a two-dimensional outline of a human (with hands that are approximately mirror images of each other) out of it, something like this human silhouette from Wikimedia Commons:

Image by Wikimedia Commons user Madhero88, used under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license.
Clearly you, as a three-dimensional being, can pick up this two-dimensional paper cutout, flip it over and set it back down as a mirror image of itself.  But can you do that for just one of the hands, leaving the rest of the figure un-mirrored?
Of course you can, but only if you fold the paper at some point along the arm.  You can even press the fold flat, flatting the folded figure (approximately) down into two dimensions, but in doing so you inevitably end up with a fold line where the map from the original figure to the folded one is not differentiable.
Worse yet, the folded figure will necessarily overlap itself near the fold line, meaning the two parts of the figure's arm will now be squished into the same area of 2D space.  For a (hypothetical two-dimensional) living organism, that sounds distinctly uncomfortable.
(You could perhaps try to avoid those issues by twisting the arm like a candy wrapper instead of folding it, but that would instead give you a single 2D point with the entire width of the arm squished into it.  Or, if you only do it approximately, a bunch of intersecting fold lines approximating the twist.)
Going back to your original scenario of a three-dimensional human's hand being turned around in 4D, something similar must inevitably happen.  While it's (geometrically) possible for our hypothetical four-dimensional being to pull the human's hand out of 3D space, turn it round in 4D and push it back into 3D space in mirrored orientation, but it's not possible to do that and push the human, including their entire arm, back into 3D in a way that doesn't tear the arm apart, create self-intersections or otherwise mutilate it.
To see this, it's not even necessary to consider all the possible 4D folds that the hypothetical being might attempt.  It's enough to observe that if a mirrored hand (made up of mirrored molecules!) is connected to a non-mirrored body, then (when the whole thing is forced back into three-dimensional space) there must be some kind of a boundary between them, and whatever happens at that boundary cannot possibly be compatible with healthy human biology.
In particular, remember that many important biomolecules (like proteins, sugars and even DNA) are chiral, i.e. not mirror symmetric.  Whatever happens at that boundary, any blood passing through it would somehow have to have its molecules converted to their mirror images (and back again when it returns), which isn't something that can just spontaneously happen in flat 3D space.  While this may not be the most obvious problem with your proposed partial body inversion, it is a rather fundamental one in the sense that it can't be overcome by surgery.

How do you know what could happen when bringing back the human from a 4D world to a 3D one?

@DavideMasi: I'm assuming that the only things that would happen are those that would be required by pure geometry. (There's a slight digression to chemistry at the end of the answer, but mostly just to illustrate the geometric fact that there must necessarily be a non-smooth boundary between an inverted hand and a non-inverted arm.) Of course we don't even know if a fourth spatial dimension exists or if it's even possible to detach a human or any other 3D object from the normal 3D space it exists in, much less what would happen to it if one tried.

Based on your comments, I think what you're after is the following.
Reflection through the x-axis in 2D space is represented by the matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 &-1\end{pmatrix}. $$
Note that this has determinant $-1$ and is orientation-reversing. Adding an extra dimension, rotation about the x-axis 180 degrees in 3D space is represented by
$$ \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}, $$
which has determinant $1$ and is orientation-preserving. Note, however, that restricted to the xy-plane, this rotation becomes exactly the earlier reflection through the y-axis. In this sense you could think of a 2D reflection as a 3D rotation.
You could do the same thing in 3D and 4D space with the matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \qquad \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}.$$
The first represents reflection through the yz-plane in 3D space, has determinant $-1$, and is orientation-reversing. The second represents a kind of rotation in 4D space, has determinant $1$, and is orientation-preserving. Note that the 4D rotation when restricted to xyz-space is exactly reflection through the yz-plane.
In what sense is the 4D matrix a rotation? It's an element of $SO(4)$, the group of orthogonal 4x4 real matrices with determinant $1$. This group is path-connected, meaning you can find a continuous sequence of such matrices starting at the identity and ending at the 4D matrix above, which would implement the rotation step-by-step while preserving all 4D distances throughout. Indeed, $O(n)$ has two connected components, of which $SO(n)$ is the component of the identity.

I think this is only half of the answer. This shows you could indeed rotate an entire 3-d human being in 4-d space so that it becomes its mirror image. But I don't think you could rotate a human being into a position where afterwards it fits back into 3-d space, has 2 right hands and has not been torn apart. That doesn't work in the 2-d to 3-d analogy either.

The question is very vague. I originally mentioned sphere eversion in the comments because it's a a continuous operation which turns a sphere inside-out without tearing or cutting. That one allows self-intersections in 3D. The details of what is and isn't possible depend immensely on the precise mathematical constraints. I picked one precise interpretation of an imprecise question. Others are welcome to decide on their own variants.

@quarague - more of a biology question, but I feel this mirror image human wouldn't survive very long? I guess all its internal molecules would be flipped and that will interfere with its ability to digest regular food. If the 4-d creature rotated its food for it regularly, it might work. On the other hand, it might be immune to many viruses.

@JoshuaP.Swanson how would one go about finding those intermediate matrices between the identity and an arbitrary rotation matrix?

@RohitPandey In general you're asking for an algorithm demonstrating that $SO(n)$ is path connected. There are many proofs you can look up and extract such a procedure from. In this specific case, you can do the following: rotate in the xy-plane 180 degrees (fixing the other coordinates), then in the yz plane 180 degrees, then in the zw-plane 180 degrees. This effectively "moves the negative" along the diagonal until the two negatives cancel.

Modeling rotations in quaternions, achieving the same result, I believe:
We can produce a two-dimensional reflection by reflection in three dimensions, since a position quaternion $\mathbf{p} = a\mathbf{i}+b\mathbf{j}$ maps continuously via conjugation by the unit rotation quaternion $\mathbf{q}(t) = \cos t+\mathbf{i}\sin t$ to $a\mathbf{i}+b(\mathbf{j}\cos 2t+\mathbf{k}\sin 2t)$, yielding (at $t = \pi/2$) $a\mathbf{i}-b\mathbf{j}$ as expected.
Analogously, both pre-multiplying and post-multiplying $\mathbf{p} = a\mathbf{i}+b\mathbf{j}+c\mathbf{k}$ by the unit rotation quaternion $\mathbf{q}(t) = \cos t + \mathbf{k}\sin t$ (a four-dimensional rotation) gives $a\mathbf{i}+b\mathbf{j}+c(\mathbf{k}\cos 2t-\sin 2t)$, yielding (at $t = \pi/2$ again) $a\mathbf{i}+b\mathbf{j}-c\mathbf{k}$ as expected: effectively a three-dimensional reflection obtained by rotation through a fourth spatial dimension.
